# Kubernetes bootstrap token

Tags: kubernetes

In the Kubernetes docs there is a `bootstrap token` which is used for Nodes TLS bootstrapping.
Wherever it is mentioned there is always the same value of `07401b.f395accd246ae52d`. I haven't found much details on if that numeric sequence have some special meaning and should be precisely the same for every bootstrapped Node. 
Or is that just a randomly generated magic number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sequence carries no special meaning. The bootstrap token is entirely random. I suspect the times that specific sequence is mentioned in documentation, it's coming from or directly copied from the same source.

> Bootstrap Tokens take the form of abcdef.0123456789abcdef. More
>   formally, they must match the regular expression
>   [a-z0-9]{6}.[a-z0-9]{16}.
>
> The first part of the token is the “Token ID” and is considered public
>   information. It is used when referring to a token without leaking the
>   secret part used for authentication. The second part is the “Token
>   Secret” and should only be shared with trusted parties.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/bootstrap-tokens/#token-format

If you want to test this, play around with kubeadm's token create. This will generate random tokens you can use to bootstrap nodes.

> kubeadm token create 
>   Synopsis This command will create a bootstrap
>   token for you. You can specify the usages for this token, the “time to
>   live” and an optional human friendly description.
>
> The [token] is the actual token to write. This should be a securely
>   generated random token of the form “[a-z0-9]{6}.[a-z0-9]{16}“. If no
>   [token] is given, kubeadm will generate a random token instead.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-token/#cmd-token-create